# What's the best way to create a menu in MIPS assembly?

Tags: loops, assembly, mips

Is is a good idea (or even possible) to simplify this code into just one .asciiz so I don't have to `li $v0, 4 / la $a0, option1_p / syscall` seven different times? This menu is on a loop so I got to believe that this will just slow down the program.

```
###########################################################
    .data
welcome_p:  .asciiz "Find how many people can legally shoot animals!\n"
menu_p:     .asciiz "Choose from the following options:\n"
option1_p:  .asciiz "1) Update the count\n"
option2_p:  .asciiz "2) Display number of licenses for particular county\n"
option3_p:  .asciiz "3) Display the county number and the number of licenses already issued to a range of counties\n"
option4_p:  .asciiz "4) Display the county number and the number of licenses already issued for all 72 counties as well as total licenses issued in the state\n"
option5_p:  .asciiz "5) Quit\n"
###########################################################
```

Also, when will I run into problems with a string of text being too long to handle?

Comment: Sure, you should only zero terminate the last line obviously so the whole thing is just one string. Also, speed should be the least of your concerns, you are going to wait for user input anyway...

Comment: What do you mean by "zero terminate the last line"?

Comment: You know that `.asciiz` means put a zero at the end? So you put a zero at every line, making them separate strings. Use whatever other directive your assembler supports (probably `.ascii` without the `z`) to not put the zero after each line.

Comment: @Jester, You should put that as an answer.  It's a pretty simple way of printing out the menu... just use `.asciiz` for the last line, all others use `.ascii` and have only one label.